# Importing H2OAutoML library - 'No module named AutoML'

Tags: python-2.7, h2o, automl

any one else unable to load the H2OAutoML library in python2.7 and/or 3.6?

I've tried these (alternatives) as per the example on http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3888/docs-website/h2o-docs/automl.html, however neither imports successfully load the AutoML Library? That is, I've tried from h2o.AutoML import H2OAutoML (or from h2o.automl import H2OAutoML).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what version of H2O did you download? you will need to download h2o from http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-vapnik/1/index.html or use the latest nightly to get automl

Answer (score 1):

H2O AutoML has been available since H2O 3.14.0.1.  If it's not available, it means you need to upgrade H2O.